# Get posts with same meta value as current post

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I thought this would be simple, but cant figure it out or find any reference online. Basically Im trying to get posts who have the same meta value for a specific key as the current post. Heres what I have so far

```
global $authordata, $post;
$authors_posts = get_posts( array(
'author' => $authordata->ID,
'post_parent' => 0,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
 array(
  'key' => 'stashkey',
  'value' => $id,
'compare' => '=' )
)
) );
```

This works fine to get all posts who have a meta value which equals the same as the current post id - but I want to get it based on having the same meta value as the current post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first get the meta value for the current post, then use it to make another query.

```
global $authordata, $post;
$my_meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'stashkey', true);
$authors_posts = get_posts( array(
'author' => $authordata->ID,
'post_parent' => 0,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
 array(
  'key' => 'stashkey',
  'value' => $my_meta,
'compare' => '=' )
)
) );
```

This will fetch the posts that have equal `stashkey` meta as current post.